# Translating a snippet of pseudocode to C

Tags: c, pseudocode

I'm given this code that I want to rewrite in C. The purpose is to multiply matrices A and B.

```
for i := 1 to n do
    for j := 1 to n do
    begin
        C[i,j] := 0;
        for k := 1 to n do
            C[i,j] := C[i,j] + A[i,k]*B[k,j]
    end;
```

My translation into C:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int n = 2; //for testing
    int i = n;
    int j = n;
    int k = n;

    int A[i][k];
    int B[k][j];
    int C[i][j];

    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<n; j++)
        {
            C[i][j]=0;
            for (int k=0; k<n; k++)
            {
                C[i][j] = C[i][j]+A[i][k]*B[k][j];
                printf("A[%d][%d]*B[%d][%d]\n", i, k, k, j);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

However, when I test it, I get n^3 outputs. Did I make an error in coding the above psuedocode? Furthermore, what is the begin and end; suppose to represent?

Comment: Why shouldn't you get n^3 outputs?  You're running the `printf` n^3 times, after all.

Comment: In addition, you are printing `A`. I think you want to print `C`.. right? So, even if your processing takes `N^3`, when you are done, you can go through all the values in `C` (`N^2`) and print it out.

Comment: Well the question I have is, to multiply two matrices is it necessary to be O(n^3)? It seems like C[i][j] is assigned a new element n^3 times, whereas there are n^2 elements in C. I understand why/how the output is n^3, but confused on the logic behind multiplying matrices A and B with the above code.

Comment: @stevendao  See [Matrix multiple example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Examples_2).  It is O(n^3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks a lot like `Pascal` vs `C`

```
for i := 1 to n do
  for j := 1 to n do
  begin  
    C[i,j] := 0;
    for k := 1 to n do
      C[i,j] := C[i,j] + A[i,k]*B[k,j]
  end;
```

"begin and end" are the Pascal equivalent of "{" and "}".

```
for (i = 1; i<= n; i++) {
  for (j = 1; j<= n; j++) {
    C[i][j] = 0;
    for (k = 1; k<= n; k++) {
      // Leave printf here to see O(n^3) computations
      C[i][j] += A[i][k]*B[k][j] ;
    }
    // Move printf outside of inner loop to only see n^2 results.
    // printf("A[%d][%d]*B[%d][%d]\n", i, k, k, j);
    printf("C[%d][%d] = %d\n", i, j, C[i][j]);
  }
}
```

---

OP may want to use `double` rather than `int`.

Comment: Thank you, I figured out my question.

Answer (score 2):

Your pseudo code is O(n^3) too so there's nothing wrong in the translation.

The begin and end is there most likely to show the scope of the second for-statement (I my opinion the indentation is enough but that might not come natural for people with a background in other languages.)